# Adding Thumbstick Input to a Queue in XNA

Tags: c#, input, xna

I'm trying to store the user's most recent controller inputs in a queue, using XNA's GamePadStates. The way I'm attempting to do this is by getting the GamePadState in the current frame, comparing it to the state in the previous frame, converting all button presses and thumbstick inputs to characters, and adding it all to a queue. Later on down the line, I check to see what the most recent inputs in the queue are, and update the game state accordingly. When the queue gets too full, the earliest inputs are removed.

However, I've run into an issue for thumbstick inputs. I'm trying to treat each directional input in a similar manner as a button press, by converting it to a character, and adding it to the queue. An example of this would be

```
if(newGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X > thumbStickDeadZone && 
oldGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X < thumbStickDeadZone &&
newGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y > -1.0f * thumbStickDeadZone &&
newGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y < thumbStickDeadZone)
{
     inputQueue.Add('9'); // 9 in this case is the character representation of "Right"
}
```

As you can see, this sort of logic is extremely messy, and gets out of control really fast, especially when checking for ordinal directions is introduced.

Is there any better way to properly write this sort of thing without causing inputs to duplicate if a direction on the thumbstick is held? The closest I've gotten to a solution is checking the last set of inputs that were added to the queue for any duplicates and removing them, which causes issues if the user presses the same direction on the thumbstick twice as two separate inputs.

*Note: 
As a requirement for the program, the most recent inputs *have* to be stored, since the program will eventually be able to check to see if certain command sequences have been entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you a thumbstick can have two states "neutral" and "direction".

So, your logic should look like this (warning, lots of pseudo-code):

```
bool thumbstickActive = false;

void CheckInput()
{
    //Pseudo-code, fix to match how you are getting the position
    Vector2 currentPostiion = thumbstick1.Position;

    if (ThumbstickInDeadZone(currentPosition))
    {
        thumbStickActive = false;
    }
    else if (!thumbStickActive)
    {
        ActionQueue.Enqueue(GetDirection(currentPosition));
        thumbStickActive = true;
    }
}
```

Basically, set a flag when the stick is returned to "neutral" and only add an action to the queue if we are coming *from* neutral. If you want to just say "wasn't the last direction", change it to:

```
Direction lastDirection = Direction.None; //Pseudo-enum

void CheckInput()
{
    //Pseudo-code, fix to match how you are getting the position
    Vector2 currentPostiion = thumbstick1.Position;
    Direction currentDirection = GetDirection(currentPosition);

    //If GetDirection returns Direction.None for neutral,
    //The old check doesn't matter.
    if (currentDirection != lastDirection)
    {
        ActionQueue.Enqueue(currentDirection);
        lastDirection = currentDirection;
    }
}
```

Still the same idea, set variables that store the "last" state, and check if that state has changed enough that you want to queue up the action.

That has two helper functions that you should already have. The first (`ThumbstickInDeadZone`) returns `true` if the thumbstick is in the neutral position and `false` otherwise. The second (`GetDirection`) returns the direction represented by the current position of the thumbstick.

Comment: Thanks. The second code sample and explanation was exactly what I was looking for, and really helped to cut some unneeded lines out of my code. I appreciate your help.